# /etc/pam.d/* How to pam_ldap output debug?

Tags: pam, webmin

I would like to use pam authentication to connect ldap users without adding thoses user to the system.

In `/etc/pam.d/webmin`  :

```
auth        required      pam_env.so debug
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so config=/etc/ldap.webmin.conf    
use_first_pass debug
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass debug
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
(...)
```

Even if a user is identifiable in the ldap, pam try anyway pam_unix.so.  How can I get why (bad password, unknown user, ...) from pam_ldap?